# window.opener.close() is not working

Tags: javascript

I am opening aspx.cs page from one html page. I want to close parent window from child window.I used window.opener.close().It is working properly in IE. But not working in mozilla browser.This is the code
HTML page;

```
 window.open("Default.aspx", null, "resizable=no,scrollbars=false,channelmode=yes,titlebar=yes,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
```

Default.aspx page

```
 if (window.opener != null) {
window.opener.open('', '_self', '');
window.opener.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, JavaScript can only close windows that were opened originally in JavaScript.

Your `window.opener.open('','_self','');` line seems to be some kind of hack to trick the browser into thinking the window was opened by JS, so while it may work in some browsers there's no reason for it to work in all of them.

Comment: i tried only window.opener.close(); also.but the same response.

Comment: @Kolink I just want you to know that this answer was super helpful, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you must give him a name and not `null`.

```
window.open("Default.aspx", "aaaa", "resizable=no,scrollbars=false,channelmode=yes,titlebar=yes,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't create a object:

```
var myWindow;


function myFunction() {
    myWindow = window.open("organization.php", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=200,left=500,width=600,height=300");
}

function closeFunction(){

    myWindow.close();


}
```